# How to make chat log with python for pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logging.basicConfig(filename='Massku_bot.txt', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG , format=FORMAT,
                    FORMAT=' %(asctime)s - %(nama)s - %(pesan)s' ,
                    d = {'nama' : 'message.chat.first_name' , 'pesan' : 'message.chat.text'},
                    logging.log('Pesan : %s' , extra=d ))
```

SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Log name and text for each message? Or only trying to initialise logging correctly to be able to log when you need to?